# Java switch/case method recomended length

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement

I'm a student and I'm working on thesis dedicated to SSL/TLS and JSSE. In examples of implementation provided by oracle (found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#AppA) I found example of implementation:

```
   public void doHandshake(SocketChannel socketChannel,
                        SSLEngine     engine,
                        ByteBuffer    myNetData, 
                        ByteBuffer    peerNetData) throws Exception {

    // 2)
    int appBufferSize = engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize();
    // 3)
    ByteBuffer myAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
    ByteBuffer peerAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);

    // 4)
    engine.beginHandshake();
    SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();

    // 5)
    while (hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED
            && hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {

        switch (hs) {

            case NEED_UNWRAP:
                // Receive handshaking data from peer
                if (socketChannel.read(peerNetData) < 0) {
                    // The channel has reached end-of-stream
                }

                // Process incoming handshaking data
                peerNetData.flip();
                SSLEngineResult res = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                peerNetData.compact();
                hs = res.getHandshakeStatus();

                // Check status
                switch (res.getStatus()) {
                    case OK:
                        // Handle OK status
                        break;

        // Handle other status: BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, BUFFER_OVERFLOW, CLOSED
                    //...
                }
                break;

            case NEED_WRAP:
                // Empty the local network packet buffer.
                myNetData.clear();

                // Generate handshaking data
                res = engine.wrap(myAppData, myNetData);
                hs = res.getHandshakeStatus();

                // Check status
                switch (res.getStatus()) {
                    case OK:
                        myNetData.flip();

                        // Send the handshaking data to peer
                        while (myNetData.hasRemaining()) {
                            socketChannel.write(myNetData);
                        }
                        break;

        // Handle other status:  BUFFER_OVERFLOW, BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, CLOSED
                    //...
                }
                break;

            case NEED_TASK:
                // Handle blocking tasks
                break;

    // Handle other status:  // FINISHED or NOT_HANDSHAKING
            //...
        }
    }

// Processes after handshaking
    //   ...
}
```

Now from what I know about correct OOP architecture, method should not be longer than 20 lines, however I find it odd that Oracle would do such basic architectural error. Anything longer than 20 lines should be slit into seperate methods, there are exceptions however. I wonder, is this one of those exceptions? And if not, what is the best way to split switch/case method into smaller methods.

Comment: Your institution may be trying to instil good habits in you, but the world is full of code that doesn't conform to what you might be taught is best practice. Even in very professional code. Do not be surprised.

Comment: There's no "correct OOP architecture", only lots of opinions on what's the correct one.

Comment: Should not be longer than 20 lines? 20 is already way too much. Around 4 or 6 lines is reasonable.

Comment: You can write any code you like in your thesis. Nobody is going to code-review it for compliance to a company standard. Your thesis is intended to expand the boundaries of knowledge, not to execute 24/7 for five years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing together terms ... that don't necessarily belong together.

You can create a great OOP design ... and still have a lot of code in each of your methods.

You can follow [clean code](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/clean-code-four-simple-design-rules/) rules, and for example avoid **any** methods that contain more than **one** [single level of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction); and the final design can be bad and "not OOP" (but I think: that is hard - if you follow all the clean code rules, you automatically create better OOP designs).

But, to answer to original question (which is actually a bad question; since it invites for opinion-based answers, such as mine): the above code is at least "not at all clean". Actually, I find it pretty horrible, and the idea to stuff "even more" into those enum cases sounds super-bad to me. And beyond that, you would not be using enums in this way - such kind of "switch" should be made invisible to client code; instead you would rely on polymorphism; and simply tell call some method on some object ...

I am practicing clean code for years by now and find that the produced code is much better to read and maintain. And in "clean code"; well, as stated: you would not put more than one switch statement into a method. Each loop around; and and each of the break-cases ... would be put in their own methods.

Many people consider that crazy, but I find it to really be the "better" approach, after practicing it for many months by now. And it really prevents me from creating code that is so un-testable as your example.

And to answer your second question: that is really tough. One would have to understand the whole design, and then, piece by piece, rip it apart and refactor its elements. But that of course requires that you have a complete set of unit / functional tests (so you are show that your changes don't break the whole thing). So, the generic recipe to "improving" such code is:

1. Understand the true cost of changing existing software. You should not change stuff just because of "bad code". You need a good (business) reason to justify the expense of changing code.
2. Ensure that you have good tests. If there are tests, measure their coverage (to assess how "good" you existing tests are). If there aren't tests ... start writing them.
3. When the tests are in place ... start to re-design, re-factor and throw away un-salvageable parts.

Answer (score 0):

Example code is just that: example code. It's not a functioning piece of software, it's just an educational tool, like a cutaway diagram. Its only purpose is to show how something works and quite often it will feature things you wouldn't put into production code.

One typical feature of example code is abandoning encapsulation and reducing the number of indirections so that things are more local and you can read the code from top to bottom, like a page of text.

This is what you see here: they try to demonstrate a step-by-step process, so they formatted the code in a way that each step follows the other in the code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most underused features of Java is the possibility to add behavior (e.g. methods) to enums. So ask yourself if the behavior needed in your example is general enough to be executed (totally or partially) by the enums themselves.